# como centralizar as abas de um TabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

Eu andei dando um pesquisada, porém não encontrei. Gostaria de saber, como centralizar as abas de um TabbedPane. Elas sempre se iniciam da esquerda, porém como são apenas duas abas, queria que elas ficassem centralizadas.

Exemplo ilustrativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo simples:**

```
package telas;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Tela1 extends JFrame {

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    public Tela1() {
        setTitle("Tela");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 1", painel1());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 2", painel2());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 300));
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tela1 tela  = new Tela1();
    }

    public JComponent painel1() {
        JPanel painel1 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label1;     
        label1 = new JLabel("Página 1");
        painel1.add(label1);
        return painel1; // retorna painel.
    }

    public JComponent painel2() {
        JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();       
        JLabel label2;
        label2 = new JLabel("Página 2");
        painel2.add(label2);
        return painel2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer centralizar os rotulos das abas? Isso não é possivel apenas utilizando o componente nativo, ele só permite posicionar na parte de cima, abaixo, ou a esquerda ou direita, como pode ser visto[aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabPlacement-int-). Você terá que criar um proprio componente baseado em JPanel para fazer esse comportamento.

Comment: Assim, obrigado !   :(

Comment: Estou olhando alguns exemplos no SOEn, caso encontre algum semelhante ao que você disse, eu posto aqui.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui desta forma:

1º - Criar esta classe

```
    import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;
    import java.awt.*;


    public class CenterTabbedPane extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

        @Override
        protected LayoutManager createLayoutManager() {
            return new TabbedPaneLayout();
        }

        class TabbedPaneLayout extends BasicTabbedPaneUI.TabbedPaneLayout {

            private Insets getVisualMargin() {
                Insets margin = new Insets(3, 0, 3, 0);
                return add(-3, -3, -4, -3, margin);
            }

            @Override
            protected void calculateTabRects(int tabPlacement, int tabCount) {
                Dimension size = tabPane.getSize();
                Insets insets = add(tabPane.getInsets(), getVisualMargin());
                Insets tabAreaInsets = getTabAreaInsets(tabPlacement);
                FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics();
                int fontHeight = metrics.getHeight();
                int selectedIndex = tabPane.getSelectedIndex();
                int tabRunOverlay;
                int i, j;
                int x, y;
                int returnAt;
                boolean verticalTabRuns = (tabPlacement == LEFT || tabPlacement == RIGHT);

                //
                // Calculate bounds within which a tab run must fit
                //
                switch (tabPlacement) {
                    case LEFT:
                        maxTabWidth = calculateMaxTabWidth(tabPlacement);
                        x = insets.left + tabAreaInsets.left;
                        y = insets.top + tabAreaInsets.top;
                        returnAt = size.height - (insets.bottom + tabAreaInsets.bottom);
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        maxTabWidth = calculateMaxTabWidth(tabPlacement);
                        x = size.width - insets.right - tabAreaInsets.right - maxTabWidth;
                        y = insets.top + tabAreaInsets.top;
                        returnAt = size.height - (insets.bottom + tabAreaInsets.bottom);
                        break;
                    case BOTTOM:
                        maxTabHeight = calculateMaxTabHeight(tabPlacement);
                        x = insets.left + tabAreaInsets.left;
                        y = size.height - insets.bottom - tabAreaInsets.bottom - maxTabHeight;
                        returnAt = size.width - (insets.right + tabAreaInsets.right);
                        break;
                    case TOP:
                    default:
                        maxTabHeight = calculateMaxTabHeight(tabPlacement);
                        x = insets.left + tabAreaInsets.left;
                        y = insets.top + tabAreaInsets.top;
                        returnAt = size.width - (insets.right + tabAreaInsets.right);
                        break;
                }

                tabRunOverlay = getTabRunOverlay(tabPlacement);

                runCount = 0;
                selectedRun = -1;

                if (tabCount == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Run through tabs and partition them into runs
                Rectangle rect;
                for (i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
                    rect = rects[i];

                    if (!verticalTabRuns) {
                        // Tabs on TOP or BOTTOM....
                        if (i > 0) {
                            rect.x = rects[i - 1].x + rects[i - 1].width;
                        } else {
                            tabRuns[0] = 0;
                            runCount = 1;
                            maxTabWidth = 0;
                            rect.x = x;
                        }
                        rect.width = calculateTabWidth(tabPlacement, i, metrics);
                        maxTabWidth = Math.max(maxTabWidth, rect.width);

                        // Never move a TAB down a run if it is in the first column.
                        // Even if there isn't enough room, moving it to a fresh
                        // line won't help.
                        if (rect.x != 2 + insets.left && rect.x + rect.width > returnAt) {
                            if (runCount > tabRuns.length - 1) {
                                expandTabRunsArray();
                            }
                            tabRuns[runCount] = i;
                            runCount++;
                            rect.x = x;
                        }
                        // Initialize y position in case there's just one run
                        rect.y = y;
                        rect.height = maxTabHeight/* - 2*/;

                    } else {
                        // Tabs on LEFT or RIGHT...
                        if (i > 0) {
                            rect.y = rects[i - 1].y + rects[i - 1].height;
                        } else {
                            tabRuns[0] = 0;
                            runCount = 1;
                            maxTabHeight = 0;
                            rect.y = y;
                        }
                        rect.height = calculateTabHeight(tabPlacement, i, fontHeight);
                        maxTabHeight = Math.max(maxTabHeight, rect.height);

                        // Never move a TAB over a run if it is in the first run.
                        // Even if there isn't enough room, moving it to a fresh
                        // column won't help.
                        if (rect.y != 2 + insets.top && rect.y + rect.height > returnAt) {
                            if (runCount > tabRuns.length - 1) {
                                expandTabRunsArray();
                            }
                            tabRuns[runCount] = i;
                            runCount++;
                            rect.y = y;
                        }
                        // Initialize x position in case there's just one column
                        rect.x = x;
                        rect.width = maxTabWidth/* - 2*/;

                    }
                    if (i == selectedIndex) {
                        selectedRun = runCount - 1;
                    }
                }

                if (runCount > 1) {
                    // Re-distribute tabs in case last run has leftover space
                    normalizeTabRuns(tabPlacement, tabCount, verticalTabRuns ? y : x, returnAt);

                    selectedRun = getRunForTab(tabCount, selectedIndex);

                    // Rotate run array so that selected run is first
                    if (shouldRotateTabRuns(tabPlacement)) {
                        rotateTabRuns(tabPlacement, selectedRun);
                    }
                }

                // Determine how much we want to pad the tabs
                int maxPad = 0;
                /*
                for (i = runCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int start = tabRuns[i];
                int next = tabRuns[i == (runCount - 1)? 0 : i + 1];
                int end = (next != 0? next - 1 : tabCount - 1);

                maxPad = Math.max(maxPad, rects[end].x + rects[end].width - rects[start].x);
                }*/
                switch (tabPlacement) {
                    case LEFT:
                    case RIGHT:
                        maxPad = size.height - tabAreaInsets.top - tabAreaInsets.bottom;
                        break;
                    case BOTTOM:
                    case TOP:
                    default:
                        maxPad = size.width - tabAreaInsets.left - tabAreaInsets.right;
                        break;
                }

                // Step through runs from back to front to calculate
                // tab y locations and to pad runs appropriately
                for (i = runCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    int start = tabRuns[i];
                    int next = tabRuns[i == (runCount - 1) ? 0 : i + 1];
                    int end = (next != 0 ? next - 1 : tabCount - 1);
                    if (!verticalTabRuns) {
                        for (j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                            rect = rects[j];
                            rect.y = y;
                            rect.x += getTabRunIndent(tabPlacement, i);
                        }
                        if (shouldPadTabRun(tabPlacement, i)) {
                            padTabRun(tabPlacement, start, end, maxPad);
                        }
                        if (tabPlacement == BOTTOM) {
                            y -= (maxTabHeight - tabRunOverlay);
                        } else {
                            y += (maxTabHeight - tabRunOverlay);
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (j = start; j <= end; j++) {
                            rect = rects[j];
                            rect.x = x;
                            rect.y += getTabRunIndent(tabPlacement, i);
                        }
                        if (shouldPadTabRun(tabPlacement, i)) {
                            padTabRun(tabPlacement, start, end, maxPad);
                        }
                        if (tabPlacement == RIGHT) {
                            x -= (maxTabWidth - tabRunOverlay);
                        } else {
                            x += (maxTabWidth - tabRunOverlay);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Pad the selected tab so that it appears raised in front
                padSelectedTab(tabPlacement, selectedIndex);

                // if right to left and tab placement on the top or
                // the bottom, flip x positions and adjust by widths
                if (verticalTabRuns) {
                    int rightMargin = size.width - (insets.right + tabAreaInsets.right);
                    for (i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
                        rects[i].x = rightMargin - rects[i].x - rects[i].width;
                    }
                }


                switch (tabPlacement) {
                    case LEFT:
                    case RIGHT: {
                        int availableTabAreaHeight = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom - tabAreaInsets.top - tabAreaInsets.bottom;
                        int usedTabAreaHeight = 0;
                        int pad = 0;
                        for (int run = 0; run < runCount; run++) {
                            int firstIndex = tabRuns[run];
                            int lastIndex = lastTabInRun(tabCount, run);
                            if (run == 0) {
                                usedTabAreaHeight = 0;
                                for (i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                                    usedTabAreaHeight += rects[i].height;
                                }
                                pad = (availableTabAreaHeight - usedTabAreaHeight) / 2;
                            }
                            for (i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                                rects[i].y += pad;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case BOTTOM:
                    case TOP:
                    default: {
                        int availableTabAreaWidth = size.width - insets.left - insets.right - tabAreaInsets.left - tabAreaInsets.right;
                        for (int run = 0; run < runCount; run++) {
                            int firstIndex = tabRuns[run];
                            int lastIndex = lastTabInRun(tabCount, run);
                            int usedTabAreaWidth = 0;
                            for (i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                                usedTabAreaWidth += rects[i].width;
                            }
                            int pad = (availableTabAreaWidth - usedTabAreaWidth) / 2;
                            for (i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                                rects[i].x += pad;
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            private Insets add(Insets i1, Insets i2) {
                return new Insets(
                        i1.top + i2.top,
                        i1.left + i2.left,
                        i1.bottom + i2.bottom,
                        i1.right + i2.right
                );
            }

            private Insets add(int top, int left, int bottom, int right, Insets i1) {
                return new Insets(
                        i1.top + top,
                        i1.left + left,
                        i1.bottom + bottom,
                        i1.right + right
                );
            }

        }

    }
```

2º - Adicioná-la ao tabbedpane

```
tabbedPane.setUI(new CenterTabbedPane());
```

---

classe teste:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Tela1 extends JFrame {
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

    public Tela1() {
        setTitle("Tela");
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 1", painel("painel 1"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Página 2", painel("painel 2"));
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), 300));
        tabbedPane.setUI(new CenterTabbedPane());
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton adicionar = new JButton("adicionar");
        adicionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int tab = tabbedPane.getTabCount() + 1;
                tabbedPane.addTab("Página " + tab, painel("painel " + tab));
            }
        });
        adicionar.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(adicionar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tela1();
    }

    public JComponent painel(String titulo) {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label;
        label = new JLabel(titulo);
        painel.add(label);
        return painel; // retorna painel.
    }

}
```

Comment: Apesar de ser uma solução interessante, você não centraliza as tabs. Nesse exemplo mesmo, se adicionar tabs em runtime, perde a centralização. E não funciona com todos os LAFs do java. Testa ai com nimbus: http://pastebin.com/RypmNQER

Comment: correto, o que eu queria passar é que seria uma propriedade de LAFs que ele poderia manipular para resolver o problema, eu não postei como comentário pois queria mostrar como o código ficaria. Vou procurar uma melhor forma de explicar.  vlw

Comment: @DavidCabral, você descobriu alguma forma de funcionar com o look&Fell ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos atualizei a resposta.. tenta agora.

Comment: Só um adento: [sempre inicie uma aplicação grafica dentro da **EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595). Achei interessante como resolveu, reescrevendo o componente, só que agora nenhum LAF aplica a ele, só o basic. Se o OP estiver usando o nimbus ou outro proprio, não vai aplicar neste componente `CenterTabbedPane`. Dai fica a criterio do OP essa perda.