# Piscar botões com Thread

Tags: java, swing

Estou com um problema ao tentar fazer  os botões piscarem.

Usando o `Thread.sleep()`,  ao clicar no botão , o `Thread.sleep()` ignora o que vem antes dele, executa o `sleep` e executa somente o que vem depois, no caso o `setBackground(Color.GRAY)`. Já procurei por soluções aqui, e ou não entendi o que queriam dizer ou não funcionava. Também tentei com a classe `Timer`, porém não consegui.

```
package exstackoverflow;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ExStackOverflow extends JFrame{

    JButton b = new JButton();
    JButton b2 = new JButton();
    JButton b3 = new JButton();
    JButton b4 = new JButton();
    int numBotao=0;

    public ExStackOverflow(){

         Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        b2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        b3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        b4.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        b.addActionListener(new botaoListener());
        b2.addActionListener(new botaoListener());
        b3.addActionListener(new botaoListener());
        b4.addActionListener(new botaoListener());

        c.add(b);
        c.add(b2);
        c.add(b3);
        c.add(b4);
        numBotao = new Random().nextInt(4);

        piscar();

        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class botaoListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
             if(ae.getSource().equals(b)){
                 numBotao=1;
                 piscar();

             }else if(ae.getSource().equals(b2)){
                 numBotao=2;
                 piscar();

             }else if(ae.getSource().equals(b3)){
                 numBotao=3;
                 piscar();

             }else if(ae.getSource().equals(b4)){
                 numBotao=4;
                 piscar();
             }
        }
    }

     public void piscar(){
        try{
            switch(numBotao){//switch baseado nos valores inseridos na lista Sequencia
                case 1:
                    b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    b2.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    b2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    b3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                    b4.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExStackOverflow().piscar();

    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel simular o problema.

Comment: Outra coisa, você precisa trabalhar com [**swingworker**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swingworker) para fazer isso, pois em swing, toda a interface gráfica roda em cima de uma thread chamada [**event-dispatch-thread**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread), e a tela só atualiza após acabem as alterações nessa interface. Ou seja, quando a EDT atualizar sua tela, já terão sido feitas as duas alterações e não vai piscar o componente.

Comment: a idéia era fazer o jogo genius. Já existem varias perguntas pra isso mas eu n vi uma solução que funcionasse. E tb é a primeira vez q vejo alguem falar sobre swingworker.

Comment: Entendo, mas sem um **[mcve]** fica até dificil dizer se swingworker é o que você precisa.

Comment: diegofm, eu editei e coloquei um novo exemplo. Por favor veja se é o suficiente pra te ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: a minha resposta lhe atendeu? Você pode aceita-la, clicando no `✅`, dessa forma ela servirá de referencia para outros usuarios. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obs.: A interface swing **deve ser sempre executada** dentro da [Event
>   Dispatch Thread (ou EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), para isso você deve sempre iniciar uma
>   janela no `main`, da forma abaixo:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>         @Override
>         public void run() {
>            new ExStackOverflow().piscar();
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> Ou utilizando lambda, no Java 8:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
>         new ExStackOverflow().piscar();
>     });
> }
> ```

---

Quando você executa uma interface em [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), ela é executada em uma Thread própria chamada [event-dispatch-thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), e esta Thread fica em loop aguardando modificações ou ações na interface. Graças a essa forma de funcionamento, você consegue aplicar ações em botões e demais componentes. Por causa desse funcionamento particular, quando você faz

```
b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
Thread.sleep(1500);
b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

A *EDT* não vai executar cada linha e exibir na interface, e sim aplicar todas as modificações e redesenhar a interface. Neste caso você ainda vai causar um freeze na interface, por causa desse `Thread.sleep`, isso só vai atrasar o redesenho da interface pela *EDT*.

O que precisa neste caso é executar a ação de `piscar()` paralelo à *EDT* para que resulte neste efeito, ou seja, precisa de uma nova Thread executando isso. Felizmente, no próprio java já há uma classe para trabalharmos com a *EDT*, se chama [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Você precisa executar nesta classe o método `piscar()` para que ele funcione como desejado:

```
public void piscar() {
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            switch (numBotao) {//switch baseado nos valores inseridos na lista Sequencia
                case 1:
                    b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    b2.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    b2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    b3.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    b4.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {

            super.done();
            try {
                get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Nesta classe há um método abstrato chamado `doInBackground()` (que é o método onde a execução paralela acontece), e é nele que você vai implementar a ação do piscar, como foi feito no código acima.

Implementei o método `done()`, pois ele é invocado quando a execução dentro do `doInBackground` termina, e chamei o método `get()` nele para que no caso de ocorrer algum problema que lance uma exceção, seja possível capturá-la e detectar o problema, pois como o `doInBackground()` executa em outra Thread e ao final retorna para a *EDT*, não teria como detectar problemas que venham a ocorrer sem chamar o `get()`.

Por último, o `execute()` para fazer o `SwingWorker` funcionar.

Ao fazer as alterações sugeridas e executar seu código, este será o funcionamento:

[image: Animação ccom o resultado]

Comment: +1, muito boa resposta. Mas eu já aproveitaria para eliminar esse `switch` horroroso (embora como essa pergunta é antiga, não sei se faria sentido fazer isso hoje).

Comment: @VictorStafusa bom, vale a pena melhorar de qualquer forma :) mas como remover o switch? Transformando em ENUM?

Comment: Primeiro crie um `private static Color[] BUTTON_COLORS = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN};` Depois, substitua o método com o `switch` por `@Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            if (numBotao >= 1 && numBotao <= 4) {
                b.setBackGround(BUTTON_COLORS[numBotao - 1]);
                Thread.sleep(300);
                b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            }
            return null;
        }`