# Como capturar cores de uma imagem em um JLabel que atrás de outro JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, imagem, jlabel

Eu preciso obter as cores do pixel de uma imagem inserida em um `JLabel` com `MouseMotionListener`, e este JLabel está sob ou atrás de outro JLabel. Eu sei que é possível obter uma cor de fundo por trás de um JLabel, mas o que eu preciso capturar são cores de uma imagem que estão inseridas em um JLabel.

Este é o código:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;


public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
{
    JFrame frame;
    Robot robot;
    JLayeredPane layeredPane;
    MouseMotionListener ml;

    robot = new Robot();
    frame = new JFrame("Pc");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
    layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                                "capture color under the label"));
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("folder/matiz.jpg"));
    label.setBounds(15, 15, 300, 300);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.red);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setBounds(60, 60, 300, 300);
    label1.setOpaque(true);
    label1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

    layeredPane.add(label, 0, 0);
    layeredPane.add(label1, 1, 0);


    frame.setSize(660, 400);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    frame.setGlassPane(layeredPane);
    layeredPane.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true); 

       ml = new MouseMotionAdapter() {

      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {

          JLabel comp = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
          Point point = evt.getLocationOnScreen();

                Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(),(int)point.getY());
                System.out.println(color);
            }
  };        
            label1.removeMouseMotionListener(ml);
            label.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código é o mesmo da outra pergunta? Tem uma linha desnecessária ai que eu te falei na resposta e você manteve.

Comment: Quando você passa o mouse sobre o label superior ele captura a cor branca e o que eu preciso que o mouse leia apenas o RGB do label que está abaixo mesmo passando o mouse sobre o branco. O evento do mouse deve desconsiderar o label superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de tudo quero deixar  dois alertas sobre seu código:

> Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro desta unica Thread. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.
>
> **Evite usar layout absoluto**, a API do swing provê de vários [Layouts Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para facilitar a vida do programador na hora de criar telas, além de tornar a tela flexivel a diferentes tamanhos de monitores e resoluções , sem que seja necessário isso ser tratado diretamente no código. Layout absoluto irá quebrar a aparencia da sua aplicação, dependendo do monitor onde a aplicação for executada.

---

Utilizando a classe [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), você consegue recuperar as cores RGB de uma imagem. Primeiro, deve-se criar uma instancia dessa classe, passando as dimensões da imagem:

```
BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Após isso,  você precisa "preencher" o buffer com a imagem. O JLabel é preenchido por um  `ImageIcon` mas o método [`drawimage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) espera um tipo `Image`. Pode-se recuperar este tipo do ImageIcon, pelo método [`getimage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage()):

```
    ImageIcon imgIcon= label.getIcon();
    Graphics g = bufImage.createGraphics();
    
    g.drawImage(imgIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
```

Com a imagem já "bufferizada", basta utilizar o método [`getRGB(x,y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)) para recuperar o valor RGB do pixel, de acordo com as coordenadas passadas pelo movimento do mouse, limitando ao tamanho da imagem:

```
    int x = (int) e.getX();
    int y = (int) e.getY();

    if(x < imgIcon.getIconWidth() && y < imgIcon.getIconHeight()){
        int rgb = bufImage.getRGB(x, y);
        System.out.println(new Color(rgb));
    }
```

Apenas inserindo estes trechos no seu método `mouseMoved` já resolveria o problema, mas para separar a responsabilidade de manusear o Label da classe principal, organizar melhor o código e tornar o componente reaproveitável, você pode criar uma classe de `JLabel` personalizada e aplicar essas alterações apenas nela. Neste caso, criei a classe `CustomLabel` para exemplificar:

```
class CustomLabel extends JLabel implements MouseMotionListener {

    private ImageIcon image;

    public CustomLabel(ImageIcon image) {
        this.image = image;
        setIcon(image);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        int x = (int) e.getX();
        int y = (int) e.getY();

        BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        Graphics g = bufImage.createGraphics();
        
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

        if(x < image.getIconWidth() && y < image.getIconHeight()){
            int rgb = bufImage.getRGB(x, y);
            System.out.println(new Color(rgb));
        }

    }
}
```

Para utilizar no seu código, basta criar esta classe no seu projeto e substituir:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("folder/matiz.jpg"));
```

por:

```
CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel(new ImageIcon("folder/matiz.jpg"));
```

---

Veja um exemplo funcional do seu código com a classe acima:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.*;

public class GetPixelImageComponent {

    public void showAndCreateGUI() throws MalformedURLException, AWTException {

        JFrame frame;
        Robot robot;
        JLayeredPane layeredPane;
        MouseMotionListener ml;

        robot = new Robot();
        frame = new JFrame("Pc");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        layeredPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("capture color under the label"));
        


        /** ESTAS DUAS LINHAS SÃO APENAS PARA DEMONSTRAÇÃO **/
        URL url = new URL("http://wimages.vr-zone.net/2013/06/10-15-2012-2-22-52-PM-300x300.png");
        CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
        
        //CustomLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("folder/matiz.jpg"));        
        label.setBounds(15, 15, 300, 300);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.black);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setBounds(60, 60, 300, 300);
        label1.setOpaque(true);
        label1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        layeredPane.add(label, 0, 0);
        layeredPane.add(label1, 1, 0);

        frame.setSize(660, 400);

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        frame.setGlassPane(layeredPane);
        layeredPane.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new GetPixelImageComponent().showAndCreateGUI();
            } catch (MalformedURLException | AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    class CustomLabel extends JLabel implements MouseMotionListener {

        private ImageIcon image;

        public CustomLabel(ImageIcon image) {
            this.image = image;
            setIcon(image);
            this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            int x = (int) e.getX();
            int y = (int) e.getY();

            BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            
            Graphics g = bufImage.createGraphics();
            
            g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

            if(x < image.getIconWidth() && y < image.getIconHeight()){
                int rgb = bufImage.getRGB(x, y);
                System.out.println(new Color(rgb));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Que resulta em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como sempre suas ajudas e respostas são fantásticas. Obrigado mais uma vez Diego! :)