# como fazer tabbedPane ocultável?

Tags: java, swing

Estou tendo problemas em tentar fazer uma aba (tabbedPane) que seja exibida de acordo com o status de um CheckBox ("selecionado/desmarcado"). 
Não sei se é possível, já que vai acabar mudando o tamanho da tela em tempo de execução.

o que eu fiz ate agora (Exemplo simples):

```
package teste02;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ExemploTela extends JFrame {

    public ExemploTela() {
        add(monta());
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public JComponent monta() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(null);
        JTextField text = new JTextField();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Exibe/Oculta");
        painel.add(label);
        label.setBounds(95, 90, 100, 25);
        label.setText("Exemplo:");
        painel.add(text);
        text.setBounds(155, 90, 200, 25);
        painel.add(check);
        check.setBounds(155, 150, 200, 25);
        painel.setBounds(1, 1, 500, 300);

        check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (check.isSelected()) {
                    add(montaAba());
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        return painel;
    }

    public JComponent montaAba() {
        JPanel aba = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Testando aba");
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);
        tabbedPane.add(label);
        aba.add(tabbedPane);
        return aba;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExemploTela x = new ExemploTela();
    }
}
```

Para Ilustrar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu até achei o erro(aliás, vários) mas não respondi poque não vejo muito sentido no que quer fazer. Pode explicar melhor o objetivo disso?

Comment: @diegofm é que quando estiver cadastrando, dependendo do produto o usuário ira ter que cadastrar "coisas a mais" (exemplo produtos com data de validade), mais, no caso de um cadastro de roupa, não precisa ter esse monte de campo a mais, ai eu queria deixar oculto, só vai aparecer se ele clicar naquele checkBox. Isso exemplo no produtos, pensei em outras utilidades em outras telas também. Se puder me dar um help, já agradeço desde já !

Comment: Mas pra que criar um tabbedpane e botar dentro de um painel então? Porque não faz direto no painel ou direto no tabbedpanel? Continuo não entendo...

Comment: @diegofm porque eu gostaria de fazer desse jeito, não queria deixar visível, mais se não tem forma de fazer, vou tentar pensar em outra coisa..

Comment: Eu não estou compreendendo sua ideia direito, poderia até da uma sugestão diferente, mas para isso, preciso entender o que está querendo fazer. Se não for pedir demais, poderia ilustrar o que pretendia fazer? Porque esse código tem uma serie de problemas, o tabbed ta sobrepondo tudo e está sendo adicionando a dois lugares, fora outros.

Comment: @diegofm vê se esta "entendível" agora.

Comment: Agora sim, deu pra entender, porque seu código faz algo muito diferente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme a ilustração, basta alternar a visibilidade do painel do TabbedPane conforme o status do checkbox, dessa forma, quando ele tiver selecionado, o `isSelected` retornará verdadeiro, exibindo o componente e vice-versa.

O código ficou assim:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ExemploTela extends JFrame {

    JComponent comp;

    public ExemploTela() {
        add(monta());
        comp = montaAba();
        comp.setVisible(false);
        add(comp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public JComponent monta() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(null);
        JTextField text = new JTextField();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Exibe/Oculta");
        painel.add(label);
        label.setBounds(95, 90, 100, 25);
        label.setText("Exemplo:");
        painel.add(text);
        text.setBounds(155, 90, 200, 25);
        painel.add(check);
        check.setBounds(155, 150, 200, 25);
        painel.setBounds(1, 1, 500, 300);

        check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    comp.setVisible(check.isSelected());
            }
        });
        return painel;
    }

    public JComponent montaAba() {
        JPanel aba = new JPanel();
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Testando aba");
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        tabbedPane.add(label);
        aba.add(tabbedPane);
        return aba;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->{
            ExemploTela x = new ExemploTela();  
        });

    }
}
```

Que resulta em:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Quero alertar que tem vários problemas nesse código, mas que fugiria do escopo da pergunta fazer alterações e explicá-las. Um deles é você iniciar a tela sem ser dentro da *Event Dispatch Thread*, pois [swing não é Thread-Safe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595), e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro desta unica Thread para evitar problemas. [**Nesta resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Outro problema é você posicionar com layout absoluto dentro do painel construído pelo método `monta()`.

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.

Sempre prefira utilizar as várias opções de Layout Managers, nos links abaixo, tem muito conteúdo a respeito:

[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

[Mais Swing: layout managers, mais componentes e detalhes](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/mais-swing-layout-managers-mais-componentes-e-detalhes/)

[Conhecendo Gerenciadores de Layout GUI do Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conhecendo-gerenciadores-de-layout-gui-do-java/25869)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. E vou ler a respeito do que você indicou, eu não sabia que a exibição pode ficar diferente dependo do monitor :( vou dar uma pesquisada mais aprofundada.