# Mudar a cor do label de acordo com estado da tela

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Estou tendo problemas para mudar a cor do conteúdo de um label, de acordo com o estado da minha tela (habilitado/desabilitado).

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para poder fazer com que ele mude a cor.

Fiz um exemplo bem simples (sem me preocupar com as melhores práticas de organização e etc)

Exemplo simplificado do código:

```
package cor;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MudaCor extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public final int DESABILITADA = 0;
    public final int HABILITADA = 1;
    public int estadoTela = DESABILITADA;

    public JPanel jpBotoes = new JPanel();
    JTextField tx1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField tx2 = new JTextField();

    private JButton botao01 = new JButton("Habilita");
    private JButton botao02 = new JButton("Desabilita");

    private String conteudo = "Teste de cor";

    public MudaCor()
    {
        setTitle("Tela de teste");
        setSize(400, 300);      
        add(posicaoComponentes());        
        habilitaComp(false);        
        estilo(conteudo);//metodo estilo        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    

    public String  estilo(String estilo)
    {
        String x = "<html><font color=#4a2d56> <b> Teste de cor </b> </font></html>"; //roxo
        String y = "<html><font color=#225218> <b> Teste de cor </b> </font></html>";//verde

        if(estadoTela != DESABILITADA)
        {
            return conteudo = x;
        }

        else
        {
            return conteudo = y;
        }        
    }       

    public JComponent posicaoComponentes()
    {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(null);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(estilo(conteudo));        
        painel.add(label);
        label.setBounds(170, 150, 100, 25);        
        painel.add(tx1);
        tx1.setBounds(130, 30, 150, 22);                            
        painel.add(tx2);       
        tx2.setBounds(130, 70, 150, 22);

        getContentPane().add("South", jpBotoes);        
        jpBotoes.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));      
        adicionaBotao(botao01);
        adicionaBotao(botao02);

        return painel;        
    }

    private void adicionaBotao(JButton botao) 
    {
        jpBotoes.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void habilitaComp(boolean status)
    {
        if(estadoTela == DESABILITADA)
        {
            tx1.setEnabled(status);
            tx2.setEnabled(status);
        }

        else
        {
            tx1.setEnabled(status);
            tx2.setEnabled(status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        if (ae.getSource() == botao01) 
        {            
            habilitaComp(true);
        } 

        else if (ae.getSource() == botao02) 
        {
            habilitaComp(false);
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MudaCor cor = new MudaCor();
        cor.setVisible(true);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Com "mudar de cor", você quer dizer mudar a cor do fundo somente, ou tambem a cor da fonte,?

Comment: Outra coisa, Frame não tem estado "desativado". E somente visivel ou não visivel.

Comment: @diegofm  Me expressei mau, quando digo habilitado/desabilitado, me referi aos componentes que estão dentro do frame (no caso os textField), eu quero mudar só a cor da fonte dentro do label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo quero deixar  dois alertas sobre seu código:

> Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois a API do swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a interface precisa iniciar dentro desta unica Thread. [Nesta resposta](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground-java.awt.Color-) explica melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.
>
> **Evite usar layout absoluto**, a API do swing provê de vários [Layouts Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para facilitar a vida do programador na hora de criar telas, além de tornar a tela flexível a diferentes tamanhos de monitores e resoluções, sem que seja necessário isso ser tratado diretamente no código. **Layout absoluto** irá quebrar a aparência da sua aplicação, dependendo do monitor onde a aplicação for executada.

---

Para alterar cor da fonte de um `JLabel`, basta utilizar o método [`setForeground()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground-java.awt.Color-), mas mesmo adicionando isso no seu código, ele jamais altera a variável `estadoTela` e o parâmetro `status` do método `habilitaComp`, que é o que você está usando para alterar o status do componente, jamais é usado.

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código, para que a cor seja alterada conforme o valor booleano passado no método `habilitaComp`, não há necessidade de criar constantes:

```
public void habilitaComp(boolean status)
{

    tx1.setEnabled(status);
    tx2.setEnabled(status);
    label.setForeground(status ? new Color(74, 45, 86) : Color.GREEN);

}
```

Com essa mudança, o método `estilo` e as constantes que você criou para controlar o estado deixam de ser necessárias, já que cria complexidade desnecessária para algo que dá para fazer utilizando operação ternária.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado ! E sobre os layouts, eu geralmente uso GridBagLayout fiz assim pra tentar fazer mais simples, apesar de realmente não ser o certo !

Comment: @G.Araujo veja a edição, da pra simplificar mais ainda, nem precisa de condicional.

Comment: essa condição ternaria, ela poderia ser usada para fazer algo parecido, só que para um "componente" do tipo Image icon ? Assim seria possível trocar o caminho de uma imagem de acordo com o "status" dos componentes?

Comment: @G.Araujo claro! no lugar do `status` você coloca uma condição qualquer que resulte em booleano, no lugar das cores, você coloca os dois caminhos que deverão ser aplicados, onde a direita do `:` é o caminho quando a condição for true, e a esquerda o caminho quando a condicao for false :)

Comment: obrigado, já deu "uma luz" essa explicação, vou tentar !

Comment: eu fiz iconeEndereco = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(status ? "/imagens/iconeAbaEndereçoDesabilitado.png" : "/imagens/iconeAbaEndereçoHabilitado.png"));   e tive que chamar o método antes de adicionar os componentes (o que eu acredito não ser o certo), e mesmo assim, ele só seta uma imagem, ele não troca conforme o "status".. alguma dica ?

Comment: @G.Araujo não estou entendendo o que você está fazendo. O que eu sugeri foi no lugar de `label.setForeground(status ? new Color(74, 45, 86) : Color.GREEN);` você poderia fazer `label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(status ? <path da imagem para true> : <path da imagem para false>));`. Se não for desse jeito dentro do `habilitaComp`, não vai funcionar.

Comment: eu crie o objeto iconeEndereco do tipo Image Icon, porque eu estava tentando fazer isso (trocar os ícones) de um tabbedPane, ai eu estava fazendo  tabbedPane.addTab("Endereços", iconeEndereco, abaEnderecos()); eu acredito que label não pode ser adicionado no tabbedPane, ou tem jeito de converter ?