# Fechar tela através do JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Estou fazendo um sistema simples de cadastro de alunos e professores e queria que, ao interagir com um `JMenuItem` chamado *sair*, o programa fechasse.

Fiz todo o algoritmo, mas esta com aquela exclamação informando que meu metodo ActionPerformed não esta sendo usado, não estou entendo esse erro segue o codigo a baixo:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Janela {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocation(400, 300);

        JMenuBar barramenu = new JMenuBar();

        //Menu Cadastro
        JMenu cadastro = new JMenu("cadastro");

        JMenuItem professor = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        JMenuItem aluno = new JMenuItem("Aluno");
        cadastro.add(professor);
        cadastro.add(aluno);

        //Menu Pesquisa
        JMenu pesquisa = new JMenu("Pesquisa");

        JMenuItem professor1 = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        JMenuItem aluno1 = new JMenuItem("aluno");
        pesquisa.add(professor1);
        pesquisa.add(aluno1);

        //Menu Excluir 
        JMenu excluir = new JMenu("Excluir");

        JMenuItem professor2 = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        JMenuItem aluno2 = new JMenuItem("aluno");
        excluir.add(professor2);
        excluir.add(aluno2);

        //Menu sistema
        JMenu sistema = new JMenu("Sistema");

        JMenuItem sobre = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        JMenuItem sair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        sistema.add(sobre);
        sistema.add(sair);

        barramenu.add(cadastro);
        barramenu.add(pesquisa);
        barramenu.add(excluir);
        barramenu.add(sistema);
        frame.getContentPane().add(barramenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);





    sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            System.exit(0);

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de tudo quero deixar um alerta:

> Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro desta unica Thread. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Para fechar a aplicação, basta chamar `dispose()` no seu frame:

```
sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           frame.dispose();

        }
    });
```

A interface [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) só possui um método, e você criou outro desnecessário e inexistente. Basta fazer isso dentro do método `actionPerformed`(Começando com "a" minúsculo).

Perceba que isso vai te forçar a tornar a variável `frame` final, por causa do escopo local dela. O ideal é trabalhar como a classe sendo inteira uma tela, estendendo `JFrame`.