# Como imprimir um ArrayList dentro de um JOptionPane?

Tags: java, arraylist

Pessoal gostaria de saber como imprimir um ArrayList dentro de um JOptionPane, deixo a baixo o codigo que estou usando mas não esta funcionando:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class repositorioPessoasLista{

    ArrayList<pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<pessoa>();
    pessoa Pessoa = new pessoa();


    public void inserir(){

        Pessoa.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome da pessoa: "));
        Pessoa.setCPF(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o CPF da pessoa: "));
        Pessoa.setIdade(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite a idade da pessoa: ")));

        pessoas.add(Pessoa);
      }

    public void pesquisar(int i){

        for(i=0 ; i < pessoas.size() ; i++){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,pessoas.get((i)));

          }



      }


}
```

e aqui esta a clase onde chamo a função pesquisar com um `ActionListener`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class janela extends JFrame {

    static repositorioPessoasLista rep = new repositorioPessoasLista();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected static JFrame frame;
    protected static JMenuBar barraMenu;
    protected static JMenu Cadastro;
    protected static JMenu Pesquisa;
    protected static JMenu Excluir;
    protected static JMenu Sistema;
    protected static JMenuItem Professorbt;
    protected static JMenuItem Aluno;
    protected static JMenuItem ProfessorPesqbt;
    protected static JMenuItem AlunoPesq;
    protected static JMenuItem ProfessorExc;
    protected static JMenuItem AlunoExc;
    protected static JMenuItem Sobre;
    protected static JMenuItem Sair;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //FRAME
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setLocation(400,300);

        //BARRA DE MENU
        barraMenu = new JMenuBar();
        Cadastro = new JMenu("Cadastro");
        Pesquisa = new JMenu("Pesquisa");
        Excluir = new JMenu("Exluir");
        Sistema = new JMenu("Sistema");
        barraMenu.add(Cadastro);
        barraMenu.add(Pesquisa);
        barraMenu.add(Excluir);
        barraMenu.add(Sistema);

        //ITENS DE MENU
        Professorbt = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        Aluno = new JMenuItem("Aluno");
        ProfessorPesqbt = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        AlunoPesq = new JMenuItem("Aluno");
        ProfessorExc = new JMenuItem("Professor");
        AlunoExc = new JMenuItem("Aluno");
        Sobre = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        Sair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        Cadastro.add(Professorbt);
        Cadastro.add(Aluno);
        Pesquisa.add(ProfessorPesqbt);
        Pesquisa.add(AlunoPesq);
        Excluir.add(ProfessorExc);
        Excluir.add(AlunoExc);
        Sistema.add(Sobre);
        Sistema.add(Sair);

        frame.add(barraMenu);
        frame.add(barraMenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //BOTAO SAIR
        Sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                int retorno = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Deseja sair ?"," ",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                if(retorno == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

                    System.exit(0);

                   }

              }


        });

        //BOTAO SOBRE
        Sobre.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SOBRE SISTEMA\n\nDesenvolvedor: Douglas Sabino\nVersão: 1.01(BETA)");

              }


        });

        //BOTAO CADASTRAR
        Professorbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                rep.inserir();

              }

        });

        ProfessorPesqbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                rep.pesquisar(0);

              }

        });

    }









}
```

Comment: Alias, pra que esse parametro ai? Pode ser ele o culpado. Remova este parametro da classe pesquisar e rode o código.

Comment: Douglas, quando adicionar código, por favor, formate-lo selecionando-o e clicando em `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes gostaria de dar 2 sugestoes:

> Procure seguir corretamente a padronização do java:
>
> - *métodos sempre devem ser iniciados com minusculo, seguindo o padrão [CamelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) para nomes compostos* e
> - *classes sempre devem iniciar com letra maiuscula, tambem seguindo o padrão CamelCase, em caso de nomes compostos.*
>
> Outra coisa é
>
> - Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info),
>     pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro
>     desta unica Thread. [Nesta
>     resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o
>     motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra
>     resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas
>     maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Não está muito claro o que "não está funcionando" na sua pergunta, por isso é importante você sempre explicar com clareza qual o problema do código, facilitando o trabalho de quem for responder.

Porém, acredito que o problema seja na hora de exibir, perceba que `pessoas.get(i)` vai recuperar um objeto do tipo `pessoa`, e se você não sobrescrever o método `toString()`, o retorno será `nomeDaClasse@hascode`, onde esse hashcode é gerado pelo proprio java.

Tente sobrescrever este método na classe pessoa desta forma:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    return "Nome: " + this.nome + " Idade: " + this.idade + " CPF: " + this.CPF;
}
```