# Como posicionar o cursor no inicio do campo?

Tags: java, swing

Como eu posso fazer um componente (`JTextField`, `JFormattedTextField` e outros) ao ser clicado/ganhar foco, posicionar o cursor na posição `0` do componente, principalmente quando o componente já estiver preenchido e o usuário clicar nele novamente? Eu estou tentando usar o `setCaretPosition(0);`

O que eu tentei:

```
package geral;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class SetaPosicao extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

    private final JTextField campo = new JTextField();
    private final JFormattedTextField campo2 = new JFormattedTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SetaPosicao tela = new SetaPosicao();
        tela.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SetaPosicao() {
        add(colocaCampo());
        setSize(500, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("#####-###");
            mf.install(campo2);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private JComponent colocaCampo() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("TextField");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Formatted");

        painel.add(label);
        painel.add(campo);
        campo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 22));
        //campo.setCaretPosition(0);

        painel.add(label2);
        painel.add(campo2);
        campo2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));
        //campo2.setCaretPosition(0);
        return painel;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        campo.setCaretPosition(0);
        campo2.setCaretPosition(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o problema ocorra porque você está tentando mudar a posição quando o *container* dos campos ganha foco, ai quando o componente de texto ganhar foco com um clique, o mouse será posicionado onde foi clicado mesmo.

Uma das formas de se resolver é aplicando o evento de foco aos dois campos de texto separadamente, e para isso, você pode criar uma classe a parte que estenda de [`FocusAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusAdapter.html) e aplicar aos dois campos:

```
class CaretPosition extends FocusAdapter{

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();           
        comp.setCaretPosition(0);
    }       
}
```

Depois é só aplicar essa classe aos campos:

```
campo.addFocusListener(new CaretPosition());
campo2.addFocusListener(new CaretPosition());
```

---

Outro problema que achei no seu código é o fato de você definir o tamanho preferido dos campos após adicioná-los. Recomendo que defina caracteristicas de todos os campos antes de adicionar eles a containers.

O código com todas as modificações fica assim:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public class SetaPosicao extends JFrame {

    private final JTextField campo = new JTextField();
    private final JFormattedTextField campo2 = new JFormattedTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            SetaPosicao tela = new SetaPosicao();
            tela.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

    public SetaPosicao() {
        add(colocaCampo());
        setSize(500, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("#####-###");
            mf.install(campo2);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private JComponent colocaCampo() {

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("TextField");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Formatted");

        campo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 22));

        campo.addFocusListener(new CaretPosition());
        campo2.addFocusListener(new CaretPosition());
        campo2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 22));

        painel.add(label);
        painel.add(campo);

        painel.add(label2);     
        painel.add(campo2);

        return painel;
    }

    class CaretPosition extends FocusAdapter{

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();           
            comp.setCaretPosition(0);
        }       
    } 
}
```

Nunca é demais informar também que aplicações swing [devem sempre serem iniciadas dentro da Thread especifca para ela, a EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193360/piscar-botoes-com-thread/193456#193456)

Comment: qual a diferença de usar JComponent e JTextComponent ? eu consigo usar no JComponent  ?

Comment: @Java JComponent é a classe que quase todos os componentes de swing herdam, ela é generica demais pro objetivo da pergunta e não possui o método `setcaretposition`, afinal, nem jpanel nem jlabel(que tambem a herdam) possuem controle de texto como jtextfield. Já JTextcomponent é herdada por jtextfield e seus subcomponentes(como jformatterdtextfield), e possui métodos de controle de texto para estes campos, é o mais recomendavel.

Comment: @Java sem contar que seu JComponent é um container que você está adicionando um monte de campos, e não só os dois de texto.

Comment: obrigado, ficou bem claro !

Answer (score -2):

O que acho que procura é no evento de **Click** algo do género

```
controlo.requestFocus()
```

O controlo de ***setCaretPosition*** devia automaticamente focar no index 0, mas só depois do ***requestFocus()***

Comment: Basta definir o setcaretposition num listener de focus no campo. Fazer dessa forma é meio que gambiarra e não é garantido o funcionamento.