# Como setar conteudo em posição 0 com campo desabilitado?

Tags: java, swing

Eu preciso que, quando o meu componente receber um texto (vai receber através de uma consulta), o texto seja "setado" no inicio do campo, pois em muitos casos, o texto é extenso e o começo acaba sendo omitido. O detalhe que está complicando a solução é que o componente esta `disable`.

Eu usei como base esta outra questão: [Como setar cursor no inicio do campo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213289/como-setar-cursor-no-inicio-do-campo)

Porém, na pergunta acima, ele faz isso através do evento de ganhar foco, o que não vai ser possível no meu caso.

Exemplo:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Position extends JFrame {

    private final JTextField campo = new JTextField();
    private JButton botao = new JButton("Clique");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Position tela = new Position();
            tela.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

    public Position() {
        add(colocaCampo());
        setSize(500, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent colocaCampo() {

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("TextField");

        campo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 22));
        campo.addFocusListener(new CaretPosition());
        painel.add(label);
        painel.add(campo);
        campo.setEditable(false);

        painel.add(botao);
        botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            campo.setText("Texto longo, realmente grande esse texto !");
        });
        botao.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 22));
        return painel;
    }

    class CaretPosition extends FocusAdapter {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            JTextComponent comp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
            comp.setCaretPosition(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Só uma correção, o campo de texto não está desabilitado, só não é editável, são duas situações bem diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu próprio código está a solução, só que colocado no lugar equivocado. Para definir a posição do *caret* de um componente de texto é através do método `setCaretPosition`, e se o texto vai ser apensado ao campo via listener de um botão, então este método deve ser chamado após a inserção do texto:

```
botao.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
    campo.setText("Texto longo, realmente grande esse texto !");
    campo.setCaretPosition(0);
});
```

Claro que essa é uma solução simplista, nada te impede em sobrescrever o método `setText` e forçar nele a posição inicial do caret, mas acredito que essa é uma alternativa que gera complexidade desnecessária.