# Aplicar foco em componente

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho um componente que é um `JPanel` que contém dois `JTextFields`, queria poder aplicar bordas e fundos so para os  `JTextFields`, sem aplicar no painel.

Eu trato tudo na tela principal para que seja aplicado para tudo que for do tipo `JComponent`, e também porque o componente poderá ser aplicado em várias telas.

Para os demais componentes como o `JTextFields` e o `JTextArea`, ele aplica corretamente.

Exemplo simplificado:

```
package focu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame implements FocusListener {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Componente:");
    private MeuComponente comp = new MeuComponente();
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel("JTextField:");
    JTextField jt = new JTextField();
    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel("JTextArea:");
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TelaPrincipal teste = new TelaPrincipal();
        teste.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TelaPrincipal() {
        setTitle("Teste");
        add(montaTela());
        //setSize(150, 300);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent montaTela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        painel.add(label);
        painel.add(comp);
        comp.addFocusListener(this);

        painel.add(label2);
        painel.add(jt);
        jt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        jt.addFocusListener(this);

        painel.add(label3);
        painel.add(area);
        area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        area.addFocusListener(this);

        return painel;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
        if (fe.getSource() instanceof JComponent) {
            ((JComponent) fe.getSource()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            ((JComponent) fe.getSource()).setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        ((JComponent) e.getSource()).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        ((JComponent) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}

class MeuComponente extends JPanel
{
    public JTextField jt01 = new JTextField();
    public JTextField jt02 = new JTextField();

    public MeuComponente()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(jt01);
        jt01.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 20));    
        add(jt02);
        jt02.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 20));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não se deve aplicar `FocusListener` a [componentes top-level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) como `JFrame`. Se o objetivo fosse controlar o foco da tela, você deve utilizar [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html).

Mas como o objetivo, ao menos pelo que entendi, é alterar características de componentes, o foco deve ser aplicado a cada um de forma individual, pois o foco não é algo compartilhado. Para isso, você precisa varrer todos os componentes da tela e, caso estes componentes sejam containers, varrer também os componentes contidos internamente.

Para tornar isso mais automatizado e flexivel a adições de novos componentes na tela, você pode resgatar uma lista de todos os componentes, através do método [`getComponents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()), e para facilitar essa varredura, uma boa solução é criar um método que contenha um laço para aplicar o listener de foco nos componentes e usar recursividade, para o caso de paineis que contenham outros paineis internos com mais componentes:

```
private void setFocusInComponents(Container container) {

    Component[] components = container.getComponents();

    for (Component comp : components) {

        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            setFocusInComponents((Container) comp);
        }

        comp.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();

                comp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
                comp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();

                comp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
                comp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Para usar o método no seu código, basta chamar `setFocusInComponents()` após adicionar todos os componentes no `JFrame`, passando o método `getcontentPane()` como parâmetro, já que este método retorna o painel que comporta tudo que é adicionado no `JFrame`.

```
setFocusInComponents(this.getContentPane());
```

Sempre é bom lembrar que aplicações swing [devem sempre serem iniciadas dentro da Thread especifca para ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193360/piscar-botoes-com-thread/193456#193456).

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, só uma dúvida, o que esse for (Component comp : components) { } ? não sabia que dava pra fazer for dessa maneira. E o método pode ser usado em JInternalFrame também ?

Comment: @Java É um laço que percorre a lista de componentes retornados pelo método `getComponentes()`. Como todo componente é um `JComponent`, todos herdam esse método. Por isso a verificação se é um tipo `Container`, já que não nos interessa percorrer componentes de um jtextfield ou de um label, já que dificilmente esses componentes guardam outros internamente.

Comment: @Java o método `setFocusInComponents()` funciona com qualquer componente que seja passado para ele, `JInternalFrame` inclui nesta lista.

Comment: na aplicação real, ele não esta funcionando. A única diferença é como eu adiciono os componentes. Lá eu uso GridBagLayout e no exemplo usei Flow

Comment: @Java mas o método não tem nada a ver com o layout. Não se esqueça de que deve ser invocado após a tela já está praticamente com todos os componentes inseridos, senão não vai funcionar mesmo. Se tiver usando nimbus como tema, pode não funcionar, pois o tema já tem as cores de foco definidas.

Comment: Então, eu havia colocado no construtor, mais, como eu tenho um método que adiciona os componentes, retirei e coloquei no final desse método, após eles adicionar os componentes, porem ele não funcionou.

Comment: @Java você está aplicando algum tema personalizado ou nimbus? Não é todo tema que aceita esse tipo de modificação. No código da pergunta é o tema mais padrão, ele aceita, mas outros temas podem se impor e não aceitar.

Comment: eu estou usando um LookAndFeel, porém funciona nele, na minha aplicação é o mesmo tema, mais n funciona

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60836/discussion-between-java-and-diegofm).