# Como inicializar um JPanel em branco?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Estou começando a trabalhar com o pacote swing e manipulação de eventos e eis que me recorreu uma ideia de testar algum programa que criasse retângulos de tamanhos e cores aleatórias. A criação do código e execução saiu tudo no previsto, exceto pelo fato de o frame já inicializar com um retângulo desenhado.

Tentei settar o background do painel como opaco e branco na inicialização mas o problema persiste.

**OBS:** A ideia do programa é que os quadrados sejam desenhados um por cima do outro mesmo.

```
public class RandomSquares {

NovoPainel painel;
JFrame frame;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomSquares rs = new RandomSquares();
    rs.construirGUI();
}

public void construirGUI() {

    frame = new JFrame("Squares");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(450,450);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    painel = new NovoPainel();

    JButton botao = new JButton("CRIAR");
    botao.addActionListener(new NovoPainel());

    frame.getContentPane().add(painel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, botao);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class NovoPainel extends JPanel implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

        int posicaoX = (int) (Math.random() * this.getWidth());
        int posicaoY = (int) (Math.random() * this.getHeight());
        int largura = (int) (Math.random() * this.getWidth() + 1);
        int altura = (int) (Math.random() * this.getHeight() + 1);

        g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        g.fillRect(posicaoX, posicaoY, largura, altura);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ev) {
        painel.repaint();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual o problema do código? Não está claro isso

Comment: Quero iniciar a aplicação com a área de desenho em branco, aí cada vez que o usuário clicar no botão, o sistema chamará repaint() que desenhará os retângulos. Porém a área de desenho já inicia desenhada.

Comment: O método paintcomponent sempre será chamado, quaisquer alterações na tela ela é redesenha, da forma que está, ate minimizando vai criar quadrados, você precisa criar um mecanismo que evite isso.

Comment: Você pode ir colocando retângulos numa lista, adicionando um sempre que o usuário clica em um botão. No paintComponent() vc pinta o fundo branco primeiro, depois, usa um foreach para percorrer a Lista de retângulos pintando cada um. :)

Comment: @Douglas não basta apenas isso, precisa de um mecanismo para controlar a criação tambem. Eu utilizaria bufferedimage, ficar fazendo laço no paintcomponent acho muito ruim, quando se tem uma classe para imagens que controla isso sem pesar a aplicação com laços.

Comment: Hum, pelo que me lembro BufferedImage te dá um Graphics2D que da pra usar pra pintar o retângulo direto no BufferedImage, então seria pintado um novo retangulo nele sempre que o botão fosse clicado. Você manteria o BufferedImage numa variável de instância e o pintaria no paintComponent() sem usar laço. Se é isso, pra mim parece bem melhor do que minha sugestão.

Comment: Bom, achei um jeito de resolver o problema, mas tem um bug chato nesse código que fica "espelhando" o botao sul na posicao norte. Estou vendo um jeito de resolver esse bug.

Comment: @Douglas é isso ai. E tirar a responsabilidade do paintcomponent de pegar esses pontos, como ele está fazendo, delegar o repaint e a criação para um método fora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de tudo deixo um alerta:

> Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info),
>   pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro
>   desta unica Thread. [Nesta
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o
>   motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas
>   maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

---

Da forma como está fazendo, você está delegando o desenho dos quadrados ao `paintComponent`, só que esse método é chamado toda vez que o componente precisa ser redesenhado, inclusive esse método é invocado assim que você instancia seu painel. Por esta razão já inicia com um desenho feito.

A solução que proponho é a seguinte:

- Utilizar `BufferedImage` para "*armazenar*" as figuras desenhadas, assim evita-se que se tenha que ficar armazenando em listas e depois percorrendo laços.
- delegar o desenho dos quadrados a um método a parte no painel, deixando o `paintComponent` apenas para atualizar o componente com a imagem do `BufferedImage`.

Aplicando as duas sugestões acima, estender `ActionListener` como está fazendo se torna desnecessário.

Alem disso, modifiquei a ação do botão, para que ele chame o método do seu painel que vai desenhar um retângulo aleatório, sempre que ele for clicado.

Com as modificações, o código fica da forma abaixo(contém comentários nas partes relevantes):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomSquares {

    NovoPainel painel;
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //aplicações swing devem iniciar SEMPRE desta forma
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            RandomSquares rs = new RandomSquares();
            rs.construirGUI();
        });

    }

    public void construirGUI() {

        frame = new JFrame("Squares");

        painel = new NovoPainel();

        JButton botao = new JButton("CRIAR");

        //sempre que clicado, vai chamar o método que
        //desenhará quadrados aleatórios no painel
        botao.addActionListener(e -> {
            painel.criarRetangulos();
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(painel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(botao, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class NovoPainel extends JPanel {

        BufferedImage image;

        public NovoPainel() {
            setLayout(null);
        }

        public void criarRetangulos() {

            //cria uma instancia de BufferedImage, se ela nao existir
            if(image == null)
                image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);            


            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

            int posicaoX = (int) (Math.random() * this.getWidth());
            int posicaoY = (int) (Math.random() * this.getHeight());
            int largura = (int) (Math.random() * this.getWidth() + 1);
            int altura = (int) (Math.random() * this.getHeight() + 1);  

            //cria graficos da imagem para que possamos "desenhar" nela
            Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
            g2.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
            g2.fillRect(posicaoX, posicaoY, largura, altura);
            //dispensa os graficos, uma vez que já concluimos o desenho
            g2.dispose();
            //redesenha a tela com um novo quadrado pintado
            repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //esta chamada SEMPRE deve ser invocada
            //antes de tudo ao reescrever o método paintComponent
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale ressaltar que o que faz com que a tela atualize imediatamente cada vez que você clica no botão é a chamada de `repaint()` logo após desenhar um retângulo aleatório, pois é este método que notifica a tela de que houve mudanças e ela precisa ser redesenhada, através do `paintComponent()`.