# como ordernar JPanel em posições diferentes?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Qual gerenciador de Layout eu devo usar para poder posicionar os painéis como na imagem ilustrativa abaixo.

Edit: Eu tenho a Classe PainelX, que eu seto no `JFrame` como posição `SOUTH`, dentro dessa classe tenho 2 painéis (Painel 02 e 03), eu quero orientar um painel a esquerda e o outro a direita.

Eu tentei aplicar o `BorderLayout` pra posicionar os painéis secundários (painel 2 e 3), porém não deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do que eu fiz:

```
package tool;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Teste extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste teste = new Teste();
        teste.setVisible(true);                
    }

    private PainelX painel = new PainelX();

    public Teste()
    {
        setSize(600, 400);
        getContentPane().add("South", painel);        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }
}

class PainelX extends JPanel
{       
    public PainelX() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.red);
        add(painel02(), BorderLayout.EAST);       
        add(painel03(), BorderLayout.WEST);        
    }

    private JComponent painel02()
    {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel teste = new JLabel("Painel 02");

        painel.add(teste);
        return painel;
    }

    private JComponent painel03()
    {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel teste = new JLabel("Painel 03");

        painel.add(teste);
        return painel;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Não vejo imagens, então não pude entender direito o que quer fazer.

Comment: @diegofm a imagem não aparece ?

Comment: É bloqueado para mim. Por isso que é importante sempre explicar textualmente, a imagem deve ser complementar e não "a" explicação.

Comment: @diegofm editei a pergunta, da uma olhada se esta compreensível.

Comment: Quer posicionar os dois paineis lado a lado? Só isso mesmo?

Comment: @diegofm não literalmente, eu quero deixar um na "estrema esquerda e direita", do jeito que eles estão no exemplo, eles estão lado a lado, só que estão juntos, eu queria que ficassem separados. Entre eles ficasse um espaço, talvez seria necessário ter um painel vazio meio, para poder dar esse espaço ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, um aviso:

> Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info),
>   pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro
>   desta unica Thread. [Nesta
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o
>   motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas
>   maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

---

É possível fazer isso de várias formas, e utilizando a grande maioria dos [layouts managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), mas o que achei menos dispendioso é utilizar [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).

Você deve definir o `BoxLayout` como layout do seu `PainelX`:

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

O construtor dessa classe exige que você passe a referencia do [container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700332/5524514) ao qual ela será aplicado e a orientação que o layout usará para organizar os componentes adicionados. Neste caso, `BoxLayout.X_AXIS` foi escolhido pois organiza os componentes adicionando horizontalmente da esquerda para a direita.

Feito isso, você pode adicionar os dois paineis, mas entre eles, adicionar um componente invisível através do método [`createHorizontalStrut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createHorizontalStrut-int-)

```
add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(50));
```

Repare que ele recebe um tamanho fixo, que será mantido entre os componentes independente do tamanho da tela. Você pode alterar conforme necessidade.

O código adaptado fica assim:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Teste extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->{
            Teste teste = new Teste();
            teste.setVisible(true);
        });                
    }

    private PainelX painel = new PainelX();

    public Teste()
    {
        setSize(600, 400);
        getContentPane().add(painel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }
}

class PainelX extends JPanel
{       
    public PainelX() 
    {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));        
        setBackground(Color.red);
        add(painel02());
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(50));
        add(painel03());
    }

    private JComponent painel02()
    {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel teste = new JLabel("Painel 02");
        painel.add(teste);
        return painel;
    }

    private JComponent painel03()
    {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel teste = new JLabel("Painel 03");
        painel.add(teste);
        return painel;
    }    
}
```

Para demonstrar melhor, veja o resultado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero deixar uma recomendação, já que você está trabalhando bastante com layouts, prefira definir tamanhos preferidos com o método `setPreferredSize` ao inves de `setSize`, pois a maioria dos layouts ignoram completamente esse ultimo.

Comment: Obrigado, alias obrigado duas vezes, uma pelo layout e outra por esse createHorizontalStrut(), nem sabia que tinha isso, eu usava JTextField com setVisible(false).; pra fazer o que isso faz. Agora posso retirar as gambiarras dos meus códigos, obrigado ! :)