# JSlider não aparece no JPanel após ser inserido

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Estava tentando adicionar um `JSlider` em um `JPanel` mas ele nao aparece.

Poderiam me dizer onde estou errando?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class Principal extends JFrame{
    public static JPanel pn = new JPanel();
    public static final int VelMin = 0;
    public static final int VelMax = 20;
    public static final int VelInit = 10;

    public static JSlider jsVelocidade= new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, VelMin, VelMax, VelInit);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Principal();
    }

    public Principal(){
        super("Semáforo");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        pn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
        pn.setLayout(null);

        jsVelocidade.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        jsVelocidade.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        jsVelocidade.setPaintTicks(true);
        jsVelocidade.setPaintLabels(true);

        pn.add(jsVelocidade);

        add(pn);
        pack();

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
pn.setLayout(null);
```

Ao fazer isso, você está removendo o *layout manager*, e sem ele, você precisa definir tamanho e posição de cada componente adicionado no painel manualmente. Remova essa linha que o componente aparece normalmente.

Mais informações a respeito de **Layout Managers** podem ser encontradas no [Guia oficial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

E sempre é bom mencionar que telas devem ser iniciadas dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro desta única *Thread*. [Nesta resposta](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) é explicado melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta *Thread*.

Comment: Mas tem como eu utilizar o JSlider sem tirar o pn.setLayout(null)?

Comment: @GustavoCruz não. Se você configura um layout como nulo, você está removendo ele do componente.