# Como colocar icon em tooltip?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Eu estou tentando imprimir um texto em um tooltip, e no final, colocar um ícone, porém eu não estou conseguindo, eu tentei fazer com html.

O problema, é que a imagem vem "quebrada", não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso?

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ToolTip extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public ToolTip() {
        add(tela());
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent tela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(jTextField);
        jTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
        jTextField.setToolTipText("Nome do campo: " + personalizaToolTip());
        return painel;
    }

    private String personalizaToolTip() {
        //JLabel label = new JLabel();
        //label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/testeIcon.png")));

        String texto = "<html><body> o campo esta desabilitado.. <img src=\"/imagens/testeIcon.png\"/> </body></html>";
        return texto;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ToolTip tp = new ToolTip();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dá para você colocar a imagem do ícone aí na pergunta?

Comment: @VictorStafusa editei !

Comment: Certo, não era bem isso o que eu queria, mas isso também ajuda bastante. O que eu estava dizendo, é colocar a imagem que você quer que apareça, a do `"/imagens/testeIcon.png"`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é apenas um circulo azul, pequeno, só pra testar.

Comment: Você precisa criar um tooltip personalizado, dessa forma ai não irá adicionar icone.

Comment: @Articuno pode me dar um exemplo, se possível ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código funciona, o problema é você adicionar texto fora das tags html, isso quebra o parse do tooltip.

Altere conforme abaixo:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTooltipImageTest extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public JTooltipImageTest() {
        add(tela());
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent tela() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(jTextField);
        jTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
        jTextField.setToolTipText(personalizaToolTip("Nome do campo: "));
        return painel;
    }

    private String personalizaToolTip(String text) {


       return "<html><body>" + text + " o campo esta desabilitado.. <img src='" + getClass().getResource("/imagens/testeIcon.png") + "' /></body></html>";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> JTooltipImageTest tp = new JTooltipImageTest());
    }
}
```

Perceba que eu apenas concatenei o seu texto dentro na string, de forma que ele suceda a tag `<html>`, pois esta deve ser [a primeira coisa da string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) para que a renderização funcione corretamente.

Veja um teste com uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero chamar a atenção pelo fato do código não ser iniciado na [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread). Torne isso um hábito, mesmo que seja num mero exemplo para postar aqui e sempre inicie a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Se tiver dúvidas sobre a importância disso,  [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado traido pelo copy&paste, corrigido,