# Como usar a biblioteca BalloonTip?

Tags: java, swing

Eu gostaria de utilizar `tooltips` como os da biblioteca [balloontip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadballoontip10jar.htm), mas não encontrei uma maneira de usar, ele parece ser diferente dos `toolTips` convencionais que para ser aplicados usam o método `setToolTipText`.

Como eu posso aplicar esse `balloontip` para um componente ?

Eu tente fazer assim:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.java.balloontip.BalloonTip;

public class TesteBalloonTip extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {            
            TesteBalloonTip tp = new TesteBalloonTip();
            tp.setVisible(true);
        }
        );        
    }

    public TesteBalloonTip() {

        BalloonTip ballon = new BalloonTip();

        ballon.setAttachedComponent(jTextField);

        setSize(500, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

porém, quando eu tento instanciar um objeto do tipo ballotip, ele me dá erro dizendo:

> BalloonTip() has protected access in BalloonTip

Comment: La tem exemplos, ja baixou os exemplos pra ver como foram feitos?

Comment: @Articuno eu baixei , executei, mais não sei como usar :(

Comment: Poste o que tentou.

Comment: @Articuno ta ali, era algo bem "simplesinho "

Comment: Percebo que não seguiu minha orientação na [ultima resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245202/28595).

Comment: @Articuno descuido meu, mais alterei agora !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Segundo a documentação**](http://timmolderez.be/balloontip/doku.php?id=balloontip:usingballoontip#my_first_balloon_tip), o construtor da classe `BaloonTip` recebe 2 parâmetros, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
BalloonTip(JComponent attachedComponent, String text);
```

O primeiro representa o componente ao qual você quer aplicar o baloon tip, o segundo é a string que representa o texto que será exibido nele.

O construtor sem parâmetros que você ta tentando usar tem [visibilidade protegida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34/28595), por esse motivo ocorre o erro.