# Botoes não são exibidos corretamente

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou tentando adicionar 2 JButtons a um programa, faço todo o processo para adicionar, mas mostra apenas um.

```
package ldegraphic;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LDEGraphic extends JFrame {
    JButton jb = new JButton("Adicionar");
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Remover");

public LDEGraphic(){       
    setTitle("Lista Duplamente encadeada");
    setSize(900, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    setLayout(null);
    jb.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 60);
    add(jb);
    jb2.setBounds(10, 30, 120, 60);
    add(jb2);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(100, 500, 60, 25);
    g.fillRect(100, 500, 60, 25);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LDEGraphic();
}

}
```

Comment: Por que está usando layout absoluto? Tem motivo especial para isso?

Comment: Nenhum motivo especial

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro que você está adicionando um botão praticamente em cima do outro, esse é o problema de usar layout absoluto sem ter absoluta certeza de como utilizar e de suas consequências. O método `setBounds` trabalha com coordenadas e dimensão, onde os dois primeiros argumentos representam, respectivamente, a posição x e y ([plano cartesiano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_coordenadas_cartesiano)) do componente na tela, e os dois restantes sua largura e altura. Apenas ajustando a posição do segundo conforme a altura do primeiro, é possível exibir ambos. Mas insisto em recomendar:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, vai ter que posicionar todos manualmente.

---

Depois você sobrescreve o método `paint`, e a documentação diz que **[é desaconselhável sobrescrever este método](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing)** em programas swing. Se quer fazer desenhos na tela, sobrescreva o método `paintComponent` de algum JPanel e adicione-o a tela. A causa de um botão não ser exibido é justamente o fato de ter sobrescrevido este método.

Outro problema que percebi é o fato de você não despachar a tela para a [**EDT**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), recomendo que [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2017/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-swing-por-que-o-m%C3%A9todo-main-deve-despachar-a-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-gui-para-a-ed/2095#2095) a importância disso e as consequencias que podem ocorrer quando não se faz isso e [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Tem mais problemas nesse código, mas foge da dúvida ficar arrumando tudo, então apenas adaptei o que foi apontado na resposta.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LDEGraphic extends JFrame {
    
    
    JButton jb = new JButton("Adicionar");
    JButton jb2 = new JButton("Remover");
    JPanel painel;

    public LDEGraphic() {
        setTitle("Lista Duplamente encadeada");
        setSize(900, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        painel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);    
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(100, 300, 60, 25);
                g.fillRect(100, 300, 60, 25);

            }
        };
        
        painel.setLayout(null);
        jb.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 60);
        painel.add(jb);
        jb2.setBounds(10, 70, 120, 60);
        painel.add(jb2);
        getContentPane().add(painel);
        
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new LDEGraphic());
    }

}
```

Comment: Fico muito grato pela resposta, gostaria de agradecer também pelas dicas, lerei e me aprofundarei no contexto, novamente grato

Comment: @DanielB na [tag swing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) tem varias respostas boas para estudo, com outras explicações que podem te ajudar tambem no aprendizado. Qualquer duvida em relação a elas, só perguntar ;)

Comment: Obrigado mesmo =D

Comment: @DanielB lembrando que, caso a resposta tenha lhe ajudado com a duvida, você [pode aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/28595) para que a questão fique como resolvida.