# Exibir JTable em vários paineis

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Como faço para que meu `JTable` seja exibido em todas as abas dentro dos painéis? Só estou conseguindo exibir na aba "Dia 5".

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class NewClass extends JFrame{

     ResultSet rst = null;
     public Container content;
     public JPanel jpDespesas, jpGerenciar, jpCofre, jpDia5, jpDia20, jpDia25;
     public JLabel jlTotal, jlTitulo, jlVencimento, jlValor, jlSemana, jlCofre;
     public JTextField jtTotal, jtTitulo, jtVencimento, jtValor, jtSemana;
     public JButton jbCalcular, jbSalvar, jbEditar, jbExcluir, jbTotal, jbCofre;
     public JTable jtbDespesas;
     public JTabbedPane jtb;

    public NewClass() {

        super("Controle financeiro");

        setLayout(null);
        setSize(680, 350);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        content = getContentPane();

        criaTela();

    }

    public void criaTela() {

        //CRIANDO JPANEL PRINCIPAL E SETANDO PROPRIEDADES
        jpDespesas = new JPanel();
        jpDespesas.setLayout(null);
        jpDespesas.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Resumo mensal"));
        jpDespesas.setBounds(20, 15, 340, 315);
        add(jpDespesas);

        //CRIANDO PAINEL COM ABAS
        jtb = new JTabbedPane();
        jtb.setBounds(15, 20, 310, 145);
        jpDespesas.add(jtb);

        jpDia5 = new JPanel();
        jpDia5.setLayout(null);
        jpDia5.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 170);
        jtb.add("Dia 5", jpDia5);

        jpDia20 = new JPanel();
        jpDia20.setLayout(null);
        jpDia20.setBounds(20, 20, 250, 170);
        jtb.add("Dia 20", jpDia20);

        jpDia25 = new JPanel();
        jpDia25.setLayout(null);
        jpDia25.setBounds(20, 20, 250, 170);
        jtb.add("Dia 25", jpDia25);

        //CRIANDO O JTABLE
        jtbDespesas = new JTable();

        //SETANDO A QUANTIDADE DE COLUNAS E SEUS RESPECTIVOS TÍTULOS
        jtbDespesas.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{}, new String[]{"Título", "Vencimento", "Valor"}));

        //SETANDO A LARGURA DE CADA COLUNA
        jtbDespesas.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
        jtbDespesas.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        jtbDespesas.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);

        //ADICIONANDO LINHAS
        DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jtbDespesas.getModel();
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{});

        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane();
        jp.setBounds(5, 10, 295, 100);
        jp.setViewportView(jtbDespesas);
        jpDia5.add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: gostaria que fosse a mesma tabela por questões de praticidade, pra que meu código não fique tão extenso, mas o importante mesmo é que apareça em todas as guias

Comment: Entao porque nao adiciona a tabela nos outros paineis? Se nao adicionar, nao vai aparecer mesmo.

Comment: eu já tentei, mas ai a tabela continua aparecendo somente em uma das guias. Quando adiciono ela em todos os painéis, ela é mostrada só na aba "Dia 25", é como se a tabela fosse pulando de painel em painel até chagar no último, que no caso é o da aba "Dia 25". Será que a única solução é criar uma table para cada painel?

Comment: Por que está usando layout absoluto? Ele está atrapalhando tudo ai

Comment: pra conseguir posicionar livremente os componentes

Comment: Péssima ideia essa, deve-se evitar usar layout absoluto, a nao ser que voce tenha alguma necessidade e que saiba bem o que está fazendo. Ele é quem ta resultando esse problema do seu codigo. Posso sugeri algo sem esse layout absoluto? Se ta dando problema, tem que remover e tentar aprender do jeito mais pratico e menos complicado.

Comment: eu to usando o layout absoluto pra conseguir ter mais controle sobre os componentes e posicionar onde eu quero, pois nos outros layouts as definições de posições já são definidas, não cosigo trabalhar muito bem, mas me sugere outra coisa por favor, preciso resolver esse probleminha

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo. Recomendo que visite e leia os links, eles serão importantes para seu aprendizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gostaria de dar duas sugestões antes:

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da interface e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, no layout absoluto, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

---

> E sempre é bom mencionar que telas devem ser iniciadas dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a interface precisa iniciar dentro desta única *Thread*. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) é explicado melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta *Thread*.

---

Além de você ter adicionado somente em um painel, mesmo adicionando em vários não seria possível da forma como está fazendo, pois cada componente só pode ser adicionado apenas uma vez em outro, de forma que o componente fará parte apenas do ultimo *container* ao qual for adicionado.

Para resolver, você precisa criar múltiplas tabelas e `JSCrollPanes`, e compartilhar apenas o `TableModel`, que é quem gerencia os dados da tabela. Assim as 3 tabelas, mesmo sendo distintas, compartilharão os mesmos dados.

Para diminuir a repetição de código criei um método que recebe um `TableModel` e devolve um `JScrollPane` já com tamanho definido e uma tabela preenchida com o `TableModel` passado como argumento.

Também removi o layout absoluto para demostrar que é possível fazer a mesma coisa sem ele e de forma bem mais simplificada, basta procurar entender como os layouts funcionam e combiná-los conforme a necessidade.

Veja o código:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    ResultSet rst = null;
    public JPanel jpDespesas, jpGerenciar, jpCofre, jpDia5, jpDia20, jpDia25;
    public JLabel jlTotal, jlTitulo, jlVencimento, jlValor, jlSemana, jlCofre;
    public JTextField jtTotal, jtTitulo, jtVencimento, jtValor, jtSemana;
    public JButton jbCalcular, jbSalvar, jbEditar, jbExcluir, jbTotal, jbCofre;
    public JTable jtbDespesas;
    public JTabbedPane jtb;

    public NewClass() {

        super("Controle financeiro");

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 350));
        criaTela();
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    public void criaTela() {

        // CRIANDO JPANEL PRINCIPAL E SETANDO PROPRIEDADES
        jpDespesas = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        jpDespesas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(340, 315));
        jpDespesas.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Resumo mensal"));
        getContentPane().add(jpDespesas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // CRIANDO PAINEL COM ABAS
        jtb = new JTabbedPane();
        jtb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(340, 315));
        jpDespesas.add(jtb);

        jpDia5 = new JPanel();
        jpDia5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 170));
        jtb.add("Dia 5", jpDia5);

        jpDia20 = new JPanel();
        jpDia20.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 170));
        jtb.add("Dia 20", jpDia20);

        jpDia25 = new JPanel();
        jpDia25.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 170));
        jtb.add("Dia 25", jpDia25);
        
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {}, new String[] { "Título", "Vencimento", "Valor" });
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});
        dtm.addRow(new Object[] {});

        jpDia5.add(getTablePane(dtm));
        jpDia25.add(getTablePane(dtm));
        jpDia20.add(getTablePane(dtm));
    }
    
    public JScrollPane getTablePane(TableModel model) {
        
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(table);
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(295, 100));
        return jp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new NewClass().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muitíssimo obrigado! Acabei de aprender um monte de coisas que não fazia nem idéia. Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: @RogérioSimsen que bom que lhe ajudou. Voce pode aceitar a resposta clicando no `v` a esquerda, para que sirva de referencia para outros com problema semelhante.