# Problema ao realizar um evento em button no Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Estou com um problema ao fazer um evento em um button (utilizando textfield para setar valores) e chamar um método para calcular o IMC (ainda não terminei esse método).

Código:
(tela.java)

```
package calculadoraimc;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
 //evento para button
import java.awt.event.*; //evento para button

public class tela extends JFrame 
{
    private IMC[] i;
    private JLabel lb1,lb2,lb3;
    private JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3;
    private JButton bt1;
    public tela(){
        setTitle("Calculadora IMC");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lb1 = new JLabel("Nome");
        tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        lb2 = new JLabel("Peso");
        tf2 = new JTextField(20);
        lb3 = new JLabel("Altura");
        tf3 = new JTextField(20);
        bt1 = new JButton ("Calcular");
        bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev){bConf();}});


        add(lb1);
        add(tf1);   
        add(lb2);
        add(tf2);
        add(lb3);
        add(tf3);
        add(bt1);
    }

    public void bConf() {
    i[Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText())].setNome(tf2.getText());// converter string para inteiro e adicionar em cliente e converte string em inteiro e adicionar em Nome
    i[Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText())].setPeso(Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText())); // converter string para inteiro e adicionar em cliente e converte string em inteiro e adicionar em codigo
    tf1.setText(" "); // limpar campos
    tf2.setText(" ");  
    }
}
```

IMC.java

```
package calculadoraimc;

public class IMC{
private String nome;
private double altura,peso,imc;

public void setNome(String n){
this.nome=n;
}
public String getNome(){
return this.nome;
}
public void setAltura(double a){
this.altura=a;
}
public double getAltura(){
return this.altura;
}
public void setPeso(double p){
this.peso=p;
}
public double getpeso(){
return this.peso;
}

public void calcularIMC(){
this.imc=this.peso/(this.altura*this.altura);
if (imc < 16.0){

            }
            if (16< imc && imc <16.99){

            }
            if (17<imc && imc <18.49){


            }
            if (18.50< imc && imc < 24.99){

            }
            if(25<imc && imc <29.99){

            }
            if(30<imc && imc <34.99){

            }
            if(35<imc && imc <39.99){

            }
            if(imc>=40){

            }
}


}
```

main:

```
package calculadoraimc;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class programa {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  tela t = new tela();
  IMC i = new IMC();
  t.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: Qual a duvida? "Estou com um problema" nao diz muito sobre o que está tentando fazer e tem dificuldades.

Comment: ue eu falei em fazer um evento no button, ao clica no button setar os valores colocados no textfield para os meus set's e chamar um metodo (que eu ainda não terminei.)

Comment: Acho que sua abordagem não está muito boa, posso sugerir uma abordagem melhor?

Comment: pode sim bro, é um trabalho de faculdade, eu tentei fazer por um exemplo que o professor me passou e infelizmente não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Gabriel, veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o objetivo e passar os valores capturados nos campos de texto ao clicar no botão, não há necessidade alguma de criar um array do tipo `IMC`. Eu sugeriria que crie um construtor que receba os valores necessários para o calculo, mais ou menos desta forma:

```
public class IMC {

//seus campos...

    public IMC(String nome, double peso, double altura) {

        this.nome = nome;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;

    }

//restante da classe...

}
```

E ao invés de iniciar no main, o que também é completamente desnecessário uma vez que o escopo da classe IMC não precisa fazer parte desta, inicie como campo da classe `Tela`:

```
public class Tela {

//...
private IMC imc;
//...

}
```

e estancie dentro do evento do botão, passando os valores:

```
bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        String nome = tf1.getText();
        double peso = Double.parseDouble(tf2.getText());
        double altura = Double.parseDouble(tf3.getText()); 

        this.imc = new IMC(nome, peso, altura);

        tf1.setText(" ");
        tf2.setText(" ");
    }
});
```

Depois basta definir onde o resultado irá aparecer na sua tela e invocar o método que calcula.

Porém, seu código tem um monte de problemas que vale salientar abaixo:

- você não está despachando sua aplicação para a [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) recomendo que leia [Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT em uma aplicação swing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595) e corrija seu código.
- sua classe não está de acordo com a [convenção do java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), onde **nomes de classes sempre devem iniciar com letra maiúscula**.
- a maioria das suas variáveis de campo tem nomes que não fazem sentido algum, o que torna seu código ilegível. Nomes de variáveis devem dizer pra que ela serve, e não ter nomes genéricos que dificultam sua identificação. O mesmo vale para nomes de métodos, eles devem dizer o que o método faz ou pra que ele serve.

É essencial seguir estas dicas para poder melhorar seus códigos e torná-los mais legíveis.

Comment: Opa essa parte de despachando para aplicação event-dispatch eu dei uma lida porém não entendi muito,  e também fiquei uma dúvida com relação a composição, tem que está dentro do construtor da tela? Pois eu botei fora e deu problema nessa parte: this.imc = new IMC(nome, peso, altura);

Comment: @GabrielCosta conforme expliquei na resposta, você precisa iniciar dentro da classe Tela, seja como campo ou como variavel local. Se continuar fazendo como estava, não irá funcionar.

Comment: @GabrielCosta quanto a despachar, você SEMPRE deve iniciar a tela  conforme mostrado no quadro amarelo dessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595

Comment: Sim, realmente eu iniciei dentro da classe tela, porém dentro do construtor public tela(){}, mano eu estava pensando em criar uma nova class c nome tela 2 e setar como visible quando clicar no botão para mostrar o resultado, é uma boa? E nesse evento do botão eu posso chamar o meu metodo que calcular o imc? ( mas creio que se eu fizer da forma que falei, não seja necessário chamar o metodo no event do botão calcular).

Comment: @GabrielCosta pra que iniciar a classe IMC sem valores? Qual a necessidade? Pra calcular, você precisará, obrigatoriamente, dos 3 valores, então, nada mais coerente do que instanciar a classe com os 3 valores. Códigos precisam ter sentido lógico com aquilo que representam, iniciar IMC sem valores não faz sentido algum.